# How to use a different subclass for List elements in a super class

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm looking for the proper way to implement generics (or some better solution with data structures) for the following four classes.  I want to be able to use the method in the base class `GetActivationResponse`.  The idea was to separate plain Java sources from sources which were dependent on the Android platform.

GetActivationResponse:

```
public class GetActivationResponse extends ResponseMessage {
    protected List<Activation> mActivations;

    public GetActivationResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        super(jsonObject);

        mActivations = new ArrayList<>();

        fromJson(jsonObject);
    }

    @Override
    public void fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        //get the response DATA.
        if(jsonObject.has("DATA")) {
            JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");
            for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                mActivations.add(new Activation(dataArray.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GetActivationResponseAndroid:

```
public class GetActivationResponseAndroid extends GetActivationResponse implements Cacheable {
    public GetActivationResponseAndroid(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        super(jsonObject);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ContentValues> getContentValuesList() {
        List<ContentValues> values = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
        for(int i = 0; i < mActivations.size(); i++) {
            values.add(((ActivationAndroid)(mActivations.get(i))).toContentValues());
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

I get a ClassCastException here, though:

`((ActivationAndroid)(mActivations.get(i))).toContentValues()`

`ActivationAndroid` is a subclass of `Activation`.  My goal is to be able to use any subclass of `Activation` as well as `Activation` itself.  I think this might involve generics.  I've tried changing the `List<Activation> mActivations` to `List<? extends Activation> mActivations`, but then the compiler tells me that the line in `GetActivationResponse` which fills the List has an error on this line:

`mActivations.add(new Activation(dataArray.getJSONObject(i)));`

Apparently `<? extends Activation>` means you can ONLY use subclasses, but not the base class itself.  **I want to have the `fromJSON` method in the base class, seeing as how it works the same with `Activation` or any of its subclasses.**

`ActivationAndroid` is a subclass of `Activation` which provides a convenience method for converting the object into a `List<ContentValues>` for use with Android database transactions:

Activation:

```
public class Activation {
    protected String mApp;
    protected boolean mActivated;

    public Activation(String app, boolean activated) {
        mApp = app;
        mActivated = activated;
    }

    public Activation(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        mApp = json.getString("APP");
        mActivated = json.getBoolean("ACTIVATED");
    }
}
```

ActivationAndroid:

```
public class ActivationAndroid extends Activation implements AndroidSerial {
    public ActivationAndroid (String app, boolean activated) {
        super(app, activated);
    }

    public ActivationAndroid (JSONObject jsonScale) throws JSONException {
        super(jsonScale);
    }

    public ContentValues toContentValues() {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DbSchema.ActivationSchema.COLUMN_ACTIVATED, mActivated);
        cv.put(DbSchema.ActivationSchema.COLUMN_APP, mApp);
        return cv;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to override `fromJson()` or implement some other method to create a new Activation (or subclass) Object. You can't arbitrarily cast a class to a subclass, unless the instance is already a subclass.

Comment: You're mistaken about bounded wildcards: `<? extends T>` includes type `T` as well as its subtypes. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html . Also, in this context, "extends" also means "implements" if we're talking about an interface.

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you for your response. I thought it worked exactly as you describe, but I get a compiler error in `GetActivationResponse` when I try this: Error:(47, 29) error: no suitable method found for add(Activation)
method Collection.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Activation cannot be converted to CAP#1)
method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Activation cannot be converted to CAP#1)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Activation from capture of ? extends Activation